# Methods of overcoming "ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousFunction" in rails or sql. (st_intersects is not a unique function name)

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, postgresql, postgis, rgeo

When I run this command in rails:

```
CensusBlockGroup.where{st_interects(:the_geom, buffer)}
```

which runs this command in SQL:

```
SELECT "census_block_groups".* FROM "census_block_groups"  WHERE (st_intersects("census_block_groups"."proj_shape_3361", '002000000300000d2...'))
```

I'm getting this error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::AmbiguousFunction: 
ERROR:  function st_intersects(geometry, unknown) is not unique
LINE 1: ...lock_groups".* FROM "census_block_groups"  WHERE (st_interse...
HINT:  Could not choose a best candidate function. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

I don't know how to add explicit type casts and honestly don't clearly understand what that even means. I see the st_intersects function above is getting passed in a second parameter that is 'unknown'. Perhaps I could "cast" that and get it to work...?

I think the problem may be that there are multiple function definitions of `st_intersects` in postgresql due to its "function overloading" feature. I'm not the first developer to install postgresql/postgis on this system, a contractor of mine did, so I'm concerned we may have duplicated our efforts.

I'm running the rails server using postgresql & postgis on an Ubuntu "12.04 LTS" VPS.

I'm pretty sure I could just reinstall postgis but that would wipe out my contractor's code that does some pretty sophisticated stuff with pg_routing which I do not want to touch. If I have to I'll just boot up a fresh linode and run the code on it but it seems kind of wasteful and perhaps even more significantly like a kind of defeat.

If I'm unable to properly solve the problem by removing the ambiguity (this normally works for me on macs and linux distros), I think another solution would be to flag postgresql to ignore the ambiguity and just choose the first st_intersects function it comes across.

Other notes:

- the geometry factory I'm using in rgeo is 'Geos'
- geometries are Cartesian, not geographic

Similar questions (that are still leaving me scratching my head as a rails developer crippled by the ORM):

- [PostGIS Error: Could not choose a best candidate function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15706888/postgis-error-could-not-choose-a-best-candidate-function)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I never worked with Rails, but indeed, in PostgreSQL the function ST_Intersects has an override, which means that depending on the type of the arguments, a different function shall be called.

In this case, those are the overrides:

> boolean ST_Intersects( geometry geomA , geometry geomB );
>
> boolean ST_Intersects( geography geogA , geography geogB );

Based on the generated query displayed by you, PostgreSQL might be having a hard time identifying which function to run, adding an explicit cast (a way to specify the type of a certain value) will tell which function should be called.

To do that in PostgreSQL simple use the "::" after a value, as:

GEOMETRY:

```
SELECT ST_Intersects('POINT(0 0)'::geometry, 'LINESTRING ( 0 0, 0 2 )'::geometry);
```

So make sure both values `:the_geom` and `buffer` matches the **geometry** type and you should be fine. Maybe ActiveRecord has a way to explicit change types? Or you can write the query directly to PostgreSQL?

(source: http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Intersects.html)

Comment: Was able to get this to work once I learned how to do a couple of things. 1.) I learned that I could create AR class scopes, then run #to_sql to them to get the SQL code to be modified 2.) generating the proper SQL strings to be executed using methods (or lambdas in my case). In my case I switched the binary looking code to WKT using the #as_text method 3. appending "EPSG=4326;" to the WKT text so that the correct SRID is taken into account by postgis. 4.) running that raw sql via `ActiveRecord::Base.connection.select_rows(sql)`

Comment: I'm not super thrilled with this isolated area of severe complexity in my code base but honestly as a rails GIS programmer, I'm not all that bothered by the obfuscated solution seeing that it works.

Comment: Glad you got it solver boulder_ruby! Just be careful with SQL injections while running RAW SQL statements.

Comment: Have come back to this question again after forgetting how I resolved it. Code as simple as this was able to fix the ambiguity issue. `where("st_intersects(proj_shape_4326, ST_GeomFromText('#{shp.as_text}',4326))")`